# buttons are not visible in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am extremely new to tkinter and need some guidance. I am trying to create three buttons on the bottom right of my screen that are side by side, but they are not appearing on my screen. The commented out parts are me troubleshooting and trying new things. There will be a graph from matplotlib that will need these buttons superimposed on so you can cycle through the data and record certain points. Here is what I have:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


    class Main(Frame):
        top = Tk()

        C = Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=700, width=700)

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            self.master.title("Project Astronomical-Yearly-Location-Apparatus")
            """self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)"""
            self.centerWindow()
            self.master.title("Buttons")
            self.style = Style()
            self.style.theme_use("default")
            frame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

            self.master.title("Commence")

            menubar = Menu(self.master)
            self.master.config(menu=menubar)

            fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Side View", command=self.side_view)
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Bye Felicia", command=self.onExit)
            menubar.add_cascade(label="Commence", menu=fileMenu)

        def side_view(self):
            t = Toplevel(self)
            t.wm_title("Side View")
            l = Label(t, text="This is window")
            l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

        def onExit(self):
            self.quit()

        def centerWindow(self):
            w = 700
            h = 700

            """self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)"""

            nextButton = Button(self, text="Next", background="green")
            nextButton.grid(row=1, column=2)

            backButton = Button(self, text="Back", background="blue")
            backButton.grid(row=1, column=3)

            recordButton = Button(self, text="Record", background="red")
            recordButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

            self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
            sw = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
            sh = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
            x = (sw - w) / 2
            y = (sh - h) / 2
            self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))


    def main():
        ex = Main()
        ex.mainloop()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: tip: you can comment out a single line with `#`

Comment: I can't run your code as it is, I get an error message `NameError: name 'Style' is not defined` please can you ensure that your code is **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable** otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported tkinter in a different way, that's why I have the "tk." before the Button and Menu objects (I think it's easier to see what's going on in the code this way -- you know where the Button and Menu objects are coming from). I think this will do what you want. Note that until you put more things inside your grid, you won't be able to move the buttons around much. Your next step here would be to add commands to the buttons to display/update an image. I suggest putting the image in a tk.Label. There's a good amount of documentation out there and I've done it myself so I may be able to help in the future.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Program with three buttons")
        self.centerWindow()

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Side View", command = self.side_view)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Bye Felicia", command = self.onExit)

        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Commence", menu=self.fileMenu)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar) # You don't have this line in the right spot, needs to be after you add_commands

    def side_view(self):
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Side View")
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window")
        l.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True,padx=100,pady=100)

    def onExit(self):
        self.destroy() # Changed to destroy

    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 700
        h = 700
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 1")
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 2")
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 3")
        self.button1.grid(row=1,column=1) 
        self.button2.grid(row=1,column=2)
        self.button3.grid(row=1,column=3)

        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        sw = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w) / 2
        y = (sh - h) / 2
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))    

main = Main()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess when I add the actual graph I will be able to move the buttons